# when copy element with background image and create png file from it using blob, get wrong image

Tags: javascript, html

cached issue when copy element with background image and create png file from it using blob, get the wrong image

1. I have a div element with a background image:
2. I created a new png file from that div
3. I changed the image in the div (different URL), In the HTML all looks good
4. Convert again this div to a png file
5. Getting the first background image in the png file

*) if I will refresh the page and then I will change the background image of the div and then I create from it the png file, It will work...

```
<div class="d-flex d-flex-1-1-auto" style="background-image: url("https://fe.io/webresources/image/show/img.png?path=dashboard/1679941/bb41d1d0-6e01-4c4d-b3bb-de3724122b1d.jpg";); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center center; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
```

I have created a new container div and copied the data to it

```
  const container = this.dom.query(SCREENSHOT_CONTAINER_SELECTOR);
  const clonedDashboard = dashboard.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement;
  this.dom.appendChild(container, clonedDashboard);
```

than I convert it to canvas:

```
canvas =  (const options: html2ImageOptions = {
      width: element.scrollWidth,
      height: element.scrollHeight,
      ...html2ImageOptions,
    };

    return htmlToImage[format](element, options);)();
```

and then using the canvas and creating from it png file

```
new Promise((resolve) => extraCanvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/png')
```

then the resolve return file (blob)
and when I call to

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        console.log(url);
```

The first time, I see that png which displays the div with the correct image.
after that (when no refresh is done)
And I changed the background image to be another image... I see it correctly on the page, but when I open the png file that was created I see that the png contain a div with the background image of the previous image that was selected

in HTML it displays the correct photo.
in the png file, it displays the first selected photo (it probably cached in the file created processed, blob)

how can I solve it?
I get a picture that represents the div with the previous image background.

After a refresh it works ok, the new image is reflected as expected in the png file

Comment: can you provide minimal reproducible on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s)? You can try this: clone the original div using [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) then assign new image to the clone then use [replaceWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith#examples) to replace the original div with the new one. Or just create a brand new div assign generated png and replace the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of caching the blob result is related to the query string in the URL.

Even the background image URL was different from each other
they were different after the query string.

the solution was to change the URL before the query string and then the blob doesn't see these URL as equal and doesn't take it from the cache

```
 const queryString = '?';
    const imageSelector = this.dom.query(this.imageWidgetSelector, widgetElement);
    const imageDivArr = imageSelector.getElementsByTagName('div');
    if (imageDivArr.length > 0) {
      const backgroundImageDivURL = imageDivArr[0].style.backgroundImage;
      const backgroundImageDivURLParts = backgroundImageDivURL.split(queryString);
      const urlWithoutQueryString = `${backgroundImageDivURLParts[0]}${Date.now()}${index}`;
      const backgroundImageDivURLWithAdditionalInfo = `${urlWithoutQueryString}${queryString}${backgroundImageDivURLParts[1]}`;
      imageDivArr[0].style.backgroundImage = backgroundImageDivURLWithAdditionalInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more code.

How are you changing the image without refreshing?  And also, after changing the image are you cloning again the `div` and then recreating the canvas?? Or if you are only switching the image and never cloning again the div, then the canvas is using the old div.

Comment: This seems to be more suitable as a comment than as a real answer.